# How to get data from returned object?

Tags: javascript

So I've some function, which returns data in new Object() inside.

Something like this:

```
function foo() {
  ...
  let arr = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
  return new Bar(arr);
}
```

console.log shows this:

```
Bar { 'one', 'two', 'three' }
```

How can I get them out?
For example, set variable first to value > 'one'

**Update:** here is what I want: https://github.com/sindresorhus/get-urls

Comment: it depends on the API provided by the `Bar` class.

Comment: Where is your definition of Bar?

Comment: hard to believe that's what you see in console

Comment: @charlietfl `Bar.prototype.toString()` could produce that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert `Set` to `Array` using `Array.from()` function

Example:

```js
function foo() {
  let arr = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
  return new Set(arr);
}

let results = Array.from(foo());

console.log(results);// print the array

let value1 = results[0]; // one
let value2 = results[1]; // two
let value3 = results[2]; // three

console.log(value1, value2, value3);
```

After that you can use the array to do whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

You should define a constructor that stores these values and some accessor method to retrieve them.